# Windows 8 Extended SplashScreen

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, splash-screen, windows-8.1

I have read many articles about extended splash screens.

So as i understood, the extended splash screen is just a control/page whatever, **that is being shown right after** the static splash screen?

But is there a way to show it instead of static splash screen?

I want to create a video splash screen, and a video starts with a gradiented background, which is not possible to set in manifest...

Comment: The default splash screen is there to guarantee that something shows when the user launches an app. Otherwise you'll have cases where the app crashes right away and nothing appears, leaving users really wondering what's going on. In short, there is not a way to bypass the default splash, so you want to make a smooth transition between that and your extended splash screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't set video as your splash screen. Though you can use such an image which can be first frame of your video. Check out [this](http://blog.rajenki.com/2013/06/creating-a-smooth-extended-splash-screen-experience/) incredible newer concept of extended splash screen.